# Regular expression for a text that contains "A-Z", "a-z", "0-9","-","()","&","/","\",","

Tags: regex

Hi I have created a regular expression that contains the letter mentioned in the title of the question. Below is the expression that I have created for a text:

```
^[0-9A-Z-():,&/\'\\.\s]+$
```

However, this is not working in case when I am entering "&" or a comma. I mean it is not allowing & and comma in the text. Am I missing something or this is not a valid expression.

Comment: Just use [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) if you don’t know. It’s not matching most characters because they aren’t escaped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) — because this ultimately answers the real question: you’ve typed a regex, don’t know why it doesn’t work, thus don’t know what it even means. The answers contain automated tools to explain regexes.

Comment: Where and how is the pattern used? Please share the code. This is no duplicate question, but certainly offtopic since no code to repro the issue is provided - [the regex matches `&`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b0-9A-Z-()%3a%2c%26%2f%5c%27%5c%5c.%5cs%5d%2b%24&i=AAA%26). Is it used in some XML?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It is not using XML. I am just using C# language for regular expression to match

Comment: @Yash - *Please share the code*. I vote to close the question unless you provide repro data.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: When I am entering "&", it is adding "&AMP;;;" automatically. This is the reason why it is not accepting &

Comment: @Yash, now, you should provide the details explaining HOW COME `&` is changed to a character entity. You say there is no XML involved, I strongly doubt that.

Comment: Do you agree your regex is working well, but your other code serializes the input text? The `&AMP;` does not match the regex due to `;`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: whenever, I was entering "&" from the UI, it is treating it as "&AMP;" and because of ";" it is not matching it. I had to explicitly handle it thru code.

Comment: That is crystal clear. However, since you haven't described your isssue in the question it is off topic. No one but you can answer the question, then why ask? Either share the code to repro or it shouldbe closed.

Answer (score 1):

The `-`, when inside square brackets takes a special meaning, and denotes a range.

`[A-Z]` denotes a range of upper case letters between `A` and `Z`. In your expression, the issue is this: `Z-(`, since the engine does not know what to do with such a range.

Change this: `^[0-9A-Z-():,&/\'\\.\s]+$` to this: `^[0-9A-Z():,&/\'\\.\s-]+$`. Notice that now, the `-` is at the end.

Comment: Hi, I have tried it, but it still not accepting "&" character. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @Yash: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using c# language

Comment: OP regex also matches `&`, so this answer does not really help. Also, a `-` after a *range* inside a character class is parsed as a literal hyphen in .NET regex, no need to put it to the end or start of the character class.

Comment: @Yash: What if you replace `:` with `\:`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regular Expression:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9&(),#&:/\s-]+$
```